# How do I take a list, collect it to a map, then sort using Java Streams?

Tags: java

I have the following code....

```
public Map<Object, Integer> getRankings(){
    Stream<String> stream = votes.stream();
    return stream
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
}
```

This works great but now I want to sort the map based on count. I tried a sort after the collect but the method isn't available because the stream is now a map. How would I sort this before returning it? Can I do it using a Stream or do I have to sort as a map?

Comment: By it's nature, `Map` does not have any ordering, so you cannot sort it. Instead, you will need to sort the map entries as a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Maps are fundamentally unsorted. You cannot therefore imply an order.

However, some specific subclasses of map do include a definition of ordering. The point is, `java.util.Map` itself does not, so we must delve into the subclasses; For example, a `new java.util.HashMap` **cannot be ordered**, period.

LinkedHashMap is sorted by 'insertion order', and thus, you can enforce an order for it.

SortedMap classes (such as TreeMap) are sorted **on key**, with a comparator, and therefore it is not possible to sort them on the value either.

The general answer is that you had some problem X and thought: I know! I'll fix this unknown problem X by having a map that is ordered by value! But it is highly unlikely that is a good way to solve X. Unfortunately, you didn't say what X is, you are merely asking questions about how to get a map sorted on values in java, and thus we're now stuck on: Ooooof, that is really hard to do.

Just in case you still think this 'map ordered on values' idea of yours is how to solve X:

There is no `.toLinkedHashMap`. There IS a variant of `Collectors.toMap` with a fourth argument which is a lambda that makes the map for you. Use that one, passing in a lambda that makes a `new LinkedHashMap`. Then you need to coerce the stream API to insert in the right order, which is impossible.

So, we need to make that possible: First collect to a plain jane map. Then re-spin that back out as a stream by asking that map for its entryset and streaming over it. Then, turn that stream into a sorted stream, sorting on `entry.getValue()`. Then collect the resulting sequential sorted stream back into a map, using one of the Collectors.toMap methods that let you provide the mapSupplier. You don't need the grouping toMap here - your stream objects are ready to be inserted verbatim.

This is of course, inefficient and has an intermediate stage map which is then immediately tossed in the garbage. But it's the only way to do this, which goes back: Having maps-sorted-on-value is rather tricky.

Comment: This is a great breakdown and I think I follow what you are saying although now I need to put together an example to be sure. You mention this would be "inefficient" but that it is the only way to do it. Is there another pattern that would fit better with what I am trying to do?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing what problem you're attempting to solve. Perhaps you can move the count into the key, at which point it's a simple matter of collecting into a TreeMap with an appropriate comparator. Possibly 'a Map' is the wrong answer entirely. I don't know without knowing why you're making that map and what that map will be used for later, and why it needs to have an order.

Comment: For example, if all you really care about is having an ordered list (ordered on 'rank', as decided by how often they show up in the input; more often = higher rank), then stop wanting a map and start wanting a collection.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the one below uses treemap but you said that was bad. The point here is just an array of strings. The number of votes (Times the string appears in the array) are then counted and converted to a map where the value is the count and the key is the object. Finally they are sorted to the person with the most votes is first etc

Comment: @Jackie you're looking for Stream's .groupingBy method.

Answer (score -1):

This solution works but I would give the check to a more "streamy" Way.

```
public Map<Object, Integer> getRankings(){
    Stream<String> stream = votes.stream();
    Map<Object, Integer> map = stream
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
    return Vote.sortByValues(map);
}

public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Comparator<K> valueComparator =  new Comparator<K>() {
        public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
            int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
            if (compare == 0) return 1;
            else return compare;
        }
    };
    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return sortedByValues;
}
```

Comment: No, making comparators that query the map to do their job doesn't work / is incredibly inefficient. It also means that any 2 different objects that have the same rank will make one of the two disappear from your TreeMap. Your TreeMap will also do bizarre things, such as lie about which elements it has (your map's .containsKey is _broken_). Don't do this.

Comment: I am not seeing this can you provide a test case that could demo this? When I tried 2 items with 2 votes each they both showed up.

Comment: `sortedByValues.containsKey("SomeObjectNotInTheMap");`